# How to add the data in jquery datatable

Tags: datatable, jquery-data

I need to add the some filter data(from the conditions) into the jquery data table. How its possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table_items').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [[ 5, "desc" ]],
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false
});

'#table_items' - the id of your table
"aaSorting": [[ 5, "desc" ]]  - here 5 is the number of column for default sorting
All columns will be sortable automatically
```

Comment: Thank you. But my quiz is .it use to the fiter the data from my condtion and add the values in to the table . Its possible?